# i did not get DataTypeName while reading the schema from the reader

Tags: c#

i can find all values but DataTypeName for particular Column field

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)
con.Open();

var QueryCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from Customers", con);
var ResultReader = QueryCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);

var dt = ResultReader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Comment: Question is unclear. In the DataTablle returned by GetSchemaTable there is a column named DataType, what do you mean with DataTypeName of a particular column?

Comment: well i needed DataType, using msSql command in the datatable i got the field for Data tape named 'DataTypeName'